# How to connect to db with docker-compose which connect to another service on local machine (redash & mysql & python_script )

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have the db, which connect to python script throw network avito_connect. This script change data in MySQL. And I want to visualise this data with redash.
Docker-compose file initialise redash with mysql_db.
But when I try add network in mysql service - redash don't see mysql db. I don't understand why.
docker-compose code below:

```
 version: '2'
x-redash-service: &redash-service
  image: redash/redash:8.0.0.b32245
  depends_on:
    - postgres
    - redis
  env_file: redash.env
  restart: always

services:
  server:
    <<: *redash-service
    command: server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      REDASH_WEB_WORKERS: 4

  scheduler:
    <<: *redash-service
    command: scheduler
    environment:
      QUEUES: "celery"
      WORKERS_COUNT: 1

  scheduled_worker:
    <<: *redash-service
    command: worker
    environment:
      QUEUES: "scheduled_queries,schemas"
      WORKERS_COUNT: 1

  adhoc_worker:
    <<: *redash-service
    command: worker
    environment:
      QUEUES: "queries"
      WORKERS_COUNT: 2

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    restart: always
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5-alpine
    env_file: redash.env
    restart: always
  nginx:
    image: redash/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - server
    links:
      - server:redash
    restart: always

  mysql:
 #   container_name: mysql_db
    image: mysql:5.7
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
    volumes:
      - /Users/zzema/Documents/Docker/selenium-template/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - /Users/zzema/Documents/Docker/selenium-template/sql_config_path:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=todos
      - MYSQL_USER=devuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret

# With this uncomment lines I can't connect to my_sql from redash
#    networks:
#      avito_connect:
#        aliases:
#          - mysql
#networks:
#  avito_connect:
#    external: true
```

I comment not working lines of code in the end of docker-compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one container to reach another, they must be on the same Docker network.

The overall networking environment you have available to you is described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  If you do nothing, Compose will create a network named `default` for you, and containers will be attached to that network.  If you declare `networks:` for a service, that replaces the `default` network unless you explicitly declare it.

If you uncomment those lines, in effect you get:

```yaml
networks:
  default: {}          # created by Compose
  avito_connect: {...} # manually created
services:
  server:
    networks:
      default: {}      # automatically inserted
  mysql:
    networks:          # no `default` because there is an explicit setting
      avito_connect: {...}
```

Now the two services aren't on the same network and can't connect to each other.

There are a couple of ways to work around this.  One is to attach the database to both networks:

```yaml
services:
  mysql:
    networks:
      default:
      avito_connect:
```

Another is to make the "default" network be the external network you're trying to connect to:

```yaml
version: '2.4' # minimum 2.1, must be later than 2(.0)
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: avito_connect
# and no networks: blocks in any service
```

Comment: Thanks, it’s helped me. I didn’t know before about default network))